# Gain root access without using root's login shell

Tags: shell, login, root, su

I bricked the login of my root user by removing zsh while it was still the default shell. Now as a result will login in fail, since on login will it try to use `/bin/zsh`(1), which is missing.

Only one other user is still available to execute code, but it has nearly no permissions. I tried elevating rights, both with `su`(2), `sudo` and various others without any success. Is there any way to fix this using command?

As a last resort would I try booting the server into a live CD and altering the file storage directly. But I would prefer avoiding this, since it would induce downtime and on failure also give me no possibility to restart all currently running services. The server is running CentOS.

(1)

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

(2)

```
$ echo my-root-password | su --shell=/bin/bash - root -c 'yum install zsh -y'
Password: su: using restricted shell /bin/zsh
su: failed to execute /bin/zsh: No such file or directory
```

(The password is piped in, because running the code is not done in an interactive shell.)

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all suggestions! Sadly none of them were applicable, so I had to settle for downtime. It took me a bit longer than I hoped, tried a lot of things which did not work but in retrospective are the following steps which solved the issue:

I changed the [boot parameters](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/reset-forgotten-root-password-centos-7-servers/) to be able to have some basic control over the server. Edited the `/etc/passwd` file, and lastly disabled SELinux since it had some policies which caused the authentication service to fail on boot.

Comment: As a non-root user with `sudo` privileges, `sudo chsh root`.

Comment: Or you can mount this drive in a Live CD and edit config files from there.

Comment: From the OP:  "As a last resort would I try booting the server into a live CD and altering the file storage directly. But I would prefer avoiding this"

Comment: In a normal configuration, you can't do this. You may have left an accidental backdoor somewhere but it's a needle in a haystack (if it wasn't, security would be easy). A session that's still open somewhere? A cron job that executes a script that you have permission to modify? Check which groups you're in, that may give a clue of what to try.

Comment: If you have FTP or SFTP (`sftp`, not `ssh`) enabled on the root account, those bypass the login shell.